# R: Replacing quotes with blank spaces

Tags: r, string, gsub

I want to replace quotes with blank spaces and want to add comma.

```
test <- c("A", "B")
test
[1] "A" "B"
gsub(pattern=""", replacement=" " , x=test)
```

**Desired Output**

```
A, B
```

Comment: `cat(test, sep = ", ")`?

Comment: Or maybe `noquote(paste(test, collapse = ", "))`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @AnandaMahto for useful comment. Would you like to change your comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider one of the following, but which is better would depend on what you are actually trying to achieve:

```
cat(test, sep = ", ")
# A, B
noquote(paste(test, collapse = ", "))
# [1] A, B
```

Comment: for the `cat` line, you can add `;cat("\n")` if you don't want the prompt to be near your line...

Comment: You can also use `print` with `quote=FALSE`.  Using `noquote` adds the noquote class

Comment: @RichardScriven, I looked at that, but then there's the problem of the comma.

Comment: Seems to be okay when you `paste`, but yes not otherwise